# Why does isinstance(number, numbers.Rational) raise TypeError when I redefine Rational?

Tags: python

Redefining Rational as a class which inherits from `numbers.Rational` causes `isinstance(number, numbers.Rational)` to raise `TypeError`, except if I also do `isinstance(number, numbers.Rational)` BEFORE defining my own Rational class, why? what am I doing wrong?

**This failes:**

```
import numbers


class RationalMeta(type, numbers.Rational):
    pass


class Rational(metaclass=RationalMeta):
    pass


print(isinstance(1, numbers.Rational))
# True

print(isinstance(1., numbers.Rational))
# TypeError: unbound method type.__subclasses__() needs an argument
```

**But this works!** for some reason:

```
import numbers


print(isinstance(1., numbers.Rational))
# False


class RationalMeta(type, numbers.Rational):
    pass


class Rational(metaclass=RationalMeta):
    pass


print(isinstance(1, numbers.Rational))
# True

print(isinstance(1., numbers.Rational))
# False
```

..the only difference being that I run `isinstance(number, numbers.Rational)` before I define my own Rational class as well.

I have spend a lot of time trying to debug what is going on here but I just can't figure it out, and I can't find anything in the documentation about this. This error seems very strange to me.

**The version of python that I am using is 3.10.0**

Comment: It is an abstract type. It is not clear what the purpose of mixing it into your metaclass is.

Comment: @MechanicPig My full code is of course a lot more complicated, this is just to replicate the error. I might well be doing it wrong, but I would still like to understand why it causes this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your implementation seems strange to me, but I will leave this aside and only discuss the cause of code failure. I don't know much about the design of the instance checking process of abstract classes (and I haven't found relevant documents for the time being), so I can only check the cause of errors directly through code.

---

The problem comes from `isinstance(1., numbers.Rational)`. `numbers.Rational` is an abstract class. It checks the type of the float object you pass in through its method `__instancecheck__`. The type of `numbers.Rational` is `ABCMeta`, so we need to check the `ABCMeta.__instancecheck__`.

If you simply view the [`abc.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/abc.py#L84) file, you will find that the `ABCMeta.__instancecheck__` completes the check by calling the `_abc_instancecheck` implemented by C:

```
# Python 3.10.8 abc.py
try:
    from _abc import (get_cache_token, _abc_init, _abc_register,
                      _abc_instancecheck, _abc_subclasscheck, _get_dump,
                      _reset_registry, _reset_caches)
except ImportError:
    from _py_abc import ABCMeta, get_cache_token
    ABCMeta.__module__ = 'abc'
else:
    class ABCMeta(type):
        ...
        def __instancecheck__(cls, instance):
            """Override for isinstance(instance, cls)."""
            return _abc_instancecheck(cls, instance)
        ...
```

It is relatively difficult to understand C code, but fortunately there is an equivalent Python implementation in [`_py_abc.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/_py_abc.py#L92). Here is the code:

```
# Python 3.10.8 _py_abc.py
class ABCMeta(type):
    ...
    def __instancecheck__(cls, instance):
        """Override for isinstance(instance, cls)."""
        # Inline the cache checking
        subclass = instance.__class__
        if subclass in cls._abc_cache:
            return True
        subtype = type(instance)
        if subtype is subclass:
            if (cls._abc_negative_cache_version ==
                ABCMeta._abc_invalidation_counter and
                subclass in cls._abc_negative_cache):
                return False
            # Fall back to the subclass check.
            return cls.__subclasscheck__(subclass)
        return any(cls.__subclasscheck__(c) for c in (subclass, subtype))
    ...
```

In fact, this is not the key point, but it is a simple explanation: at this time, the two incoming arguments, `cls` and `instance`, are respectively `numbers.Rational` and `1.`, so the `subclass` and `subtype` are both class float, `subclass is subtype` is true, and `cls._abc_negative_cache` is empty initially, so `cls.__subclasscheck__(subclass)` continues to be called here. The `ABCMeta.__subclasscheck__` code is as follows:

```
# Python 3.10.8 _py_abc.py
class ABCMeta(type):
    ...
    def __subclasscheck__(cls, subclass):
        """Override for issubclass(subclass, cls)."""
        if not isinstance(subclass, type):
            raise TypeError('issubclass() arg 1 must be a class')
        # Check cache
        if subclass in cls._abc_cache:
            return True
        # Check negative cache; may have to invalidate
        if cls._abc_negative_cache_version < ABCMeta._abc_invalidation_counter:
            # Invalidate the negative cache
            cls._abc_negative_cache = WeakSet()
            cls._abc_negative_cache_version = ABCMeta._abc_invalidation_counter
        elif subclass in cls._abc_negative_cache:
            return False
        # Check the subclass hook
        ok = cls.__subclasshook__(subclass)
        if ok is not NotImplemented:
            assert isinstance(ok, bool)
            if ok:
                cls._abc_cache.add(subclass)
            else:
                cls._abc_negative_cache.add(subclass)
            return ok
        # Check if it's a direct subclass
        if cls in getattr(subclass, '__mro__', ()):
            cls._abc_cache.add(subclass)
            return True
        # Check if it's a subclass of a registered class (recursive)
        for rcls in cls._abc_registry:
            if issubclass(subclass, rcls):
                cls._abc_cache.add(subclass)
                return True
        # Check if it's a subclass of a subclass (recursive)
        for scls in cls.__subclasses__():
            if issubclass(subclass, scls):
                cls._abc_cache.add(subclass)
                return True
        # No dice; update negative cache
        cls._abc_negative_cache.add(subclass)
        return False
    ...
```

Because float is not a virtual subclass of `numbers.Rational`, and it is not in the `Rational._abc_negative_cache`, the previous 80% of the code fails. Finally, `ABCMeta` attempts to use the subclass of `numbers.Rational` to check:

```
        ...
        # Check if it's a subclass of a subclass (recursive)
        for scls in cls.__subclasses__():
            if issubclass(subclass, scls):
                cls._abc_cache.add(subclass)
                return True
        ...
```

This will be checked along each class in MRO of your `RationalMeta`. The first one is `type`. `issubclass(type, float)` gives false, and then check `numbers.Rational`. At this time, the code returns to `ABCMeta.__subsubclasscheck__`, and then comes to the above code segment again. Since the first superclass of `RationalMeta` is `type`, this will try to call `type.__subclasses__()`. However, due to **metaclass confusion** (refer to [Special method lookup](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup)), the error occurs here (this seems to be an implementation error that could have been avoided), and causes the entire inspection process to fail.

---

Reasons for the work of the second code segment:

It is relatively simple here, because you used `isinstance(1., numbers.Rational)` to check once before building `RationalMeta`. This makes the float type cached by `numbers.Rational._abc_negative_cache`, and the result is directly obtained through caching during the second check, avoiding the call of `type.__subclasses__`.

Comment: What's odd to me is that defining `__main__.Rational` should *not* interfere with`numbers.Rational` at all. I haven't worked through the cache lookup in detail, but it seems like it's erroneously conflating the two classes just because they share the same `__name__` attribute.

Comment: @chepner `__main__.Rational` does not interfere with `numbers.Rational`. The interference item is `RationalMeta`, which becomes a subclass of `numbers.Rational` and causes different inspection behaviors.

Comment: Ok, that's what I missed.

Comment: @chepner Changing the names doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: Very nice explanation! thx!. Do you think that this kind of error should be permissible when people do such "stupid" things like what I did, or do you think that `isinstance(..)` should be more robust against such abuse? Personally I tend to think the second...

Comment: @Vinzent In fact, if there is no metaclass confusion, it can work normally and return false. "Stupid" inheritance should not be the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I try to test this, and it works:

```
class RationalMeta(type, numbers.Rational):
    pass


class Rational(metaclass=RationalMeta):
    pass


print(isinstance(1, numbers.Rational))
# True

print(isinstance(1., Rational))
# False
```

Also I try this to confirm the type.

```
import numbers

print(type(1))
# <class 'int'>
print(numbers.Rational)
# <class 'numbers.Rational'>
print(isinstance(1, numbers.Rational))
# True

print(type(1.))
# <class 'float'>
print(numbers.Rational)
# <class 'numbers.Rational'>
print(isinstance(1., numbers.Rational))
# False

class RationalMeta(type, numbers.Rational):
    pass


class Rational(metaclass=RationalMeta):
    pass

print(type(1.))
# <class 'float'>
print(numbers.Rational)
# <class 'numbers.Rational'>
print(isinstance(1., numbers.Rational))
# TypeError: unbound method type.__subclasses__() needs an argument
```

I read the documentary which said, (link is https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html)

The numbers module (PEP 3141) defines a hierarchy of numeric abstract base classes which progressively define more operations. **None of the types defined in this module are intended to be instantiated.**

class numbers.Number
The root of the numeric hierarchy. If you just want to check if an argument x is a number, without caring what kind, use isinstance(x, Number).

I just guess:

```
print(isinstance(1., numbers.Rational))
```

before **class**, and be stored in memory after running, so maybe it was the reason you can run the second one. Hope it helps.